# Basic question about Linked List in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

Let head be pointing to the first element of the following linked list 1->2->3->Null
each element of the list is a Node() with attributes : val and next

when :

```
curr=head
head=head.next
curr.next.val= 1000
#here head.val outputs 1000 : We changed the value of the 2nd node
```

But when :

```
curr=head
head=head.next
curr.next= Node(1000)
#here head.val outputs 2, it seems that the change
#we made in the previous line didn't
#affect the node but rather created a new 'route'.
```

Could someone explain why in the first case we're modifying the node value w.r.t head and in the 2nd case we're not?

Thank you

Comment: please have a look at the markdown guidlines on how to format a question (it is not quite HTML)

Comment: question was edited

Answer (score 0):

Consider 3 nodes n1, n2, n3 in a linked list.

```
head = n1
curr = head
# All n1, head and curr will be pointing to same memory.
head = head.next
# head will be reasigned to n2, but curr points to n1 itself.
```

1st case

```
curr.next.val = 1000
# curr.next is same as n1.next which is n2 so n2.val becomes 1000
# As head points to n2 head.val is also 1000
```

2nd case

```
curr.next = node(1000)
# it reassigns curr.next i.e n1.next to new node with val = 1000 (head is unaltered)
# Here as head points to n2, head.val = 2
```

#### So important thing here is `head = head.next` reassigns only `head` not `curr`